# Git terminated push command

Tags: git, github

I had a local repository mapped to a remote branch. I committed some changes to my local repository and hence it became ahead of remote by couple of changes.

I issued **git push** but it was taking a lot of time, hence I terminated the command. 
Now its showing local branch is up-to-date with remote but remote is not having those two commits :( where local is having those two.

 any ideas on how to get out of this mess and push those commits to remote.

Update: It seems changes are there in remote but somehow in Github commit history those commits are not listed. Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Update: As it turned out, it was a sync issue, commits are reflecting in the history now, although after few hours from commit :).

Comment: What happens if you `git fetch`? It should update your remote branch.

Comment: git fetch does nothing. Everything remains as it is :(.

Comment: use this command 'git push branchname'

Comment: use this this command 'git branch' and please tell me what it is showing.

Comment: its just listing all the branches including this one as well.

Comment: please show me the results and tell me on which branch you are performing  push?

Answer (score 0):

`git push <remote> -f <local_branch>:<remote_branch>`

This will do a force push to your remote branch.

ALERT: It will push whatever you have in your local branch to the remote branch invariably & if you have anything on your remote that is not in your local branch, it will be lost. I'm suggesting this solution because you said `git fetch` does nothing. So, I'm assuming you have everything from your remote branch into your local branch already.